# Big O with recursion

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, big-o

My AP comp sic class just recently went over Big O in a few basic sorting algorithms. I am a bit confused though on how it works with recursion and when I went to other stack overflow answers, I wasn't quite sure how they were getting their multiples of n for each level of the recursive function and adding them into their final answer.

I wanted to find the Big-O notation for node.nodeSortTest(int[] someArray) in this class that I made up. 
How would I get to the answer and what would it be?

```
public class node{

    public int value;

    public node higher = null;
    public node lower = null;

    //Making it a public static object was just easier for the test
    public static int addIndex = 0;

    public node(int i){
        value = i;
    }

    public void addToNode(int i){
        if(i>=value)
            if(higher != null) higher.addToNode(i);
            else higher = new node(i);
        else
            if(lower != null) lower.addToNode(i);
            else lower = new node(i);   
    }

    public static void nodeSortTest(int[] nums){
        if(nums.length<2)
            return;
        node keyNode = new node(nums[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++)
            keyNode.addToNode(nums[i]);
        node.addIndex = 0;
        keyNode.addTo(nums);
    }

    public void addTo(int[] nums){
        if(lower != null) lower.addTo(nums);
        nums[addIndex] = value;
        addIndex++;
        if(higher != null) higher.addTo(nums);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess the best case complexity of this is O(n log2n).  Looks like you are storing the nodes in a binary tree.  For each node, you insert it in a binary tree, and that would be log2n traversals.  I'm not sure I exactly understand what the addTo does (stores the location of the sorted node in the nums array?), but it looks like it takes O(log2n) to do it, so overall its O(n log2n).

Comment: Your posting is too "unstarted" for Stack Overflow; this is not a homework or tutorial site.  You've handed us your homework problem without attempting even a partial solution; instead, work as far as you can, and then bring up a specific point that stops you.

Comment: At worst case it could be O(n^2) if the tree is completely unbalanced (e.g., if you start with a sorted or reverse sorted array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some code to prompt for a value of `n` and to calculate the number of operations on an array of `n` random integers.  The tests seem to be consistent with the `O(n log2n)` theory:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Node{

    public int value;

    public Node higher = null;
    public Node lower = null;

    //Making it a public static object was just easier for the test
    public static int addIndex = 0;
    public static int numOps = 0;

    public Node(int i){
        value = i;
    }

    public void addToNode(int i){
        if(i>=value)
            if(higher != null) higher.addToNode(i);
            else higher = new Node(i);
        else
            if(lower != null) lower.addToNode(i);
            else lower = new Node(i);
        numOps++;
    }

    public static void nodeSortTest(int[] nums){
        if(nums.length<2)
            return;
        Node keyNode = new Node(nums[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++)
            keyNode.addToNode(nums[i]);
        Node.addIndex = 0;
        keyNode.addTo(nums);
    }

    public void addTo(int[] nums){
        if(lower != null) lower.addTo(nums);
        nums[addIndex] = value;
        addIndex++;
        if(higher != null) higher.addTo(nums);
        numOps++;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random r = new Random();
        System.out.print("Enter size of array: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        int [] arrayToSort = new int [n];
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
            arrayToSort[i] = r.nextInt(100000);
        }
        for (int i: arrayToSort) {
            System.out.print(i+",");
        }
        System.out.println();
        nodeSortTest(arrayToSort);
        for (int i:arrayToSort) {
            System.out.print(i+",");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\n\n\nn=" + arrayToSort.length + ", numOps=" + numOps);
        double log2n = Math.log(n)/Math.log(2);
        System.out.println("\n\nValue of n=" + n + " times log2n=" + log2n + " = " + n*log2n);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We usually have two components to the complexity:

1. Depth of the call tree
2. Breadth of iterations in each call.

In this case, you split the problem roughly in half on each recursive call: this gives you log2(n) calls deep.

At each level, you process every element of the array: dig through the code to see how that happens; use paper and pencil if that helps you visualize the work.  This adds a factor of **n** for each level of depth in that call stack.

The result is the n * log2(n) complexity that David Choweller already gave you.